# How can I inverse the arrow position of a column using GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am using a GWT UI and I need to inverse the arrow on name column.
It is coming by default with the arrow up, I want it to come down...
Do you have any idea how can I do that?
Do I have to change something in the java code or a css file?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I'd use transform: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to touch the Java code.

The method you are looking for is [here](https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/apidocs-table/gwt/material/design/client/ui/table/cell/Column.html#setDefaultSortAscending-boolean-), it's a method of the class Column for table cell

```java
public final void setDefaultSortAscending(boolean isAscending);

Set whether or not the default sort order is ascending.

Parameters:
isAscending - true to set the default order to ascending, false for descending
```

Comment: the columns are created with ColumnConfig class and there is no property where I can set descending or ascending on it...

Comment: It was easier to guess if you tell it.. :) There is an option to set the comparator. You could invert it